# Lossless mp4 is smaller than sum of frames

Tags: video

Any explanation why a mp4 comprised of png would be smaller than all of it's images? Ultimately, I would like to lower the quality of my renders (png) if they are being butchered during "lossless" encoding. Why wait 2 minutes for each render when they eventually get dissolved to a lower resolution during processing? So what's the target png file size for lossless mp4 files to converge on a sum of their parts? Sorry if this question get's asked a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If what you would like to do is to lower the file size of your images, the best way to do it would be to turn up the PNG compression to 100%. Blender has it at 15% by default. Don't worry, the *PNG compression in Blender is lossless*, which means that there will be no reduction in image quality whatsoever. The only con is that it may take a few seconds or so longer in order to deal with compression, but I find that the reduced space on the computer is well worth it.

There shouldn't be anything to worry about in terms of compiling images into a video. I would speculate that videos are more optimized for rapid viewing which could be why the files size is smaller than an equal number of videos.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean like why a MP4 of whatever number of frames occupies less storage than the frames individually?.
thats because a still frame stores more color information than a video (in most cases) and a video is a compression of frames played together as a single file instead of thousands. ideally in your case, if what u want is quality, you would want to render the frames at a higher resolution and then render the video at your desired resolution so that way compression isnt as bad. if youre uploading to youtube it will get compressed by the site anyway.

Comment: I'll reword it. MP4 "lossless" is visibly lower quality than the individual png that it is made up of. I don't know how to quantify the loss, but if I could - I would limit the resolution of each render to never exceed that quality. I'm guessing that MP4 or the android I'm playing it on is limited to a certain bitrate. My PNGs are huge! 250 frames equals ~3 GB. My video is usually 50MB. I need to make this process more lean, please help.

Comment: in that case you would want to use AVI instead of MP4 since its noticeably higher quality, AVI is lossless compared to regular MP4, the video is limited by the container so rendering it as AVI will allow a higher quality image, only disadvantage though is file sizes are huge and it might not be supported everywhere

Comment: Thanks! I went with MKV and it works great on android, but surprisingly not in windows 10. I wonder if youtube will accept mkv format, just to reduce my losses.